# XSLT with different closing tags

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file and I just want to get the value "off" but the closing tags are not the same.  I've tried wild cards but it did not work.  Any ideas?? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openremote xmlns="http://www.openremote.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openremote.org http://www.openremote.org/schemas/controller.xsd">
 <status id="5572173">off</status>
</openremote>
```

This is the xslt i've tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="*/status id="5572173"> 
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do you mean the closing tags are not the same? I see an opening and closing `openremote` tag and I see an opening and closing `status` tag.

Comment: what do you mean by "closing tags are not the same" and "it did not work"? Post your xslt what you have tried so far.

Comment: I mean  they do not match so opening is <status id="5572173"> and closing is </status>

Comment: Do you know something about attributes in XML?

Comment: As you can guess I am a complete beginner so no.

Comment: I don't like riddles :) Then you can have a look at (for example)) http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp to start with XML

Comment: Ok so I guess you mean this is an attribute not an element.  But I still can't find a simple instruction for getting at the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the value of an attribute, use the `@` prefix before it...

```
<xsl:value-of select="*/status/@id" />
```

This gets the value of the `@id`. If you want to get the `status` element for which the `id` is a specific value, do this (using square brackets to indicate a condition to filter the `status` elements select).

```
<xsl:value-of select="*/status[@id='5572173']" />
```

However.... Your XML has a namespace declaration in (indicated by `xmlns`), to complicate matters...

```
<openremote xmlns="http://www.openremote.org" ..
```

`xmlns` is not an attribute, but is declaring a default namespace to which the element, and descendants, belong. This means an element named `status` which is in a namespace, is different to one named `status` that is not in a namespace. Your XSLT needs to account for this, as currently it is looking for an element with no namespace.

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                 xmlns:o="http://www.openremote.org">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  />

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="*/o:status[@id='5572173']" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the prefix `o` is arbitary. It is the namespace URI ("http://www.openremote.org" in this case) that must match.

Read up on namespaces at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html and http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/ for example)

Comment: Thanks Tim I'm getting a result but it is the the status id number 5572173  I need the value "on"